# Structure of pointers to function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

if I have a structure that has a pointer to a function like this

```
struct str{
 int some_element;
 char other_element;
 int (*my_pointer_to_a_function)(int);
};

struct str my_struct;
int my_function(int);
```

and I asign values to it

```
my_struct.some_element = 1;
my_struct.other_element = 'a';
my_struct.my_pointer_to_a_function = my_function;
```

how do I call the function that the pointer is pointing to (using the pointer)?
My initial guess is this:

```
my_struct.(*my_pointer_to_a_function)(value);
```

or should it be

```
 *my_struct.my_pointer_to_a_function(value);
```

?

Thank you.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm programming in plain C.

Comment: Tried compiling ? and running? I am saying so because it's better to see first what the compiler does.

Comment: did u try this?:- `my_struct.my_pointer_to_a_function(value);`

Comment: this should work `my_struct.my_pointer_to_a_function(value);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointers to functions can be used as-is, without any dereference:

```
my_struct.my_pointer_to_a_function(value)
```

But if you insist in dereferencing it you have to use parenthesis this way:

```
(*my_struct.my_pointer_to_a_function)(value)
```

They both are totally equivalent, so I recommend the first one, that is simpler.

About you first try:

```
my_struct.(*my_pointer_to_a_function)(value); //Error!
```

That won't work because the expression in parenthersis has to be evaluated first: `*my_pointer_to_a_function`, but that alone means nothing.

And your second:

```
*my_struct.my_pointer_to_a_function(value); //Error!
```

The operator precedence rules evaluates first the `.`, then the function call, and lastly the `*`:

```
*(my_struct.my_pointer_to_a_function(value)); //Error!
```

So the function would be called, but the result of the call, an `int`, would be dereferenced, hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have pointer to function as you struct member like:

```
    struct newtype{
        int a;
        char c;
        int (*f)(struct newtype*);
    } var;
    int fun(struct newtype* v){
        return v->a;
    }
```

You can call it as follows:

```
    int main(){
        var.f=fun;
        var.f(&var);
     //  ^.....^..... have to pass `var` as an argument to f() :( :(
    }

 //Comment: here in var.f(&var); I miss this pointer and C++,
```

So for your case it should be just `my_struct.my_pointer_to_a_function(value);`

Additionally points:
Important to note in my example  even you wants to access members of same structure  variable you have to pass that. (its quite dissimilar than c++ object!)
virtual functions in C++ classes. They are implemented in a similar fashion under the hood.

Here is a project that will help you to use: [Function pointers inside structures](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
#define function mystruct.my_pointer_to_a_function
```

Then you can call the function :

```
int i = function(value);
```

Comment: I don't think the compiler directive `#typedef` exists! Maybe you mean `#define`. Not that it is a good idea anyway...

Comment: @rodrigo Yeah , it is a typos,I just find it after your down vote!

Comment: @rodrigo why? I find it used a lot before.

Comment: @LidongGuo Because it doesn't add any value. Instead, it adds confusion about what `function` really is...

Comment: @rodrigo when use C to write code like override , create a function pointer table and define it .

Comment: @LidongGuo Besides, what makes you think it was rodrigo's downvote?

Comment: @rodrigo I have to leave now . but I will back at night

Comment: @glglgl: Actually it was my downvote :(. I find of good manners to explain my (very few) downvotes. I did because "(unnecesary) macros are evil"!

Comment: @rodrigo Oh, ok! I always thought that we would see your decrease in reputation (-1) then. But these seem to be hidden.

Comment: @LidongGuo Whatever "night" means on a site where people worldwide participate :-)

Comment: @glglgl I am back now, and the "(unnecesary) macros are evil" convince me.There are lots things I still need to learn.Thanks.